# How can I achieve a column type HTML layout of items with just CSS (2 columns, equal height)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid-layout

So basically I have any number of items, usually between 5-10 items. I want to order these in 2 columns of equal height, or as close to equal as possible (odd number of items). For example:

1  5
 2  6
 3  7
 4

What I definitely don't want is something where it depends on the height like this:

1  6
 2  7
 3
 4
 5

I know I can count the length of the array and divide by two to get the max index for the first column like below, but I want to achieve this in just CSS:

```
Math.ceil(( ITEMS.length / 2)) - 1; // Input of 9 outputs 4 as the max index
```

I have tried using Flex and Grid but can't seem to get something to work correctly but I'm more than likely just missing something.

Comment: Use [css columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns)

Comment: Could you please clarify. Are you looking for a solution where the height is always four values and dependent on the amount of values, the rest values will tilt over to column 2. The column 2 can be either empty of filled with values.

Comment: @Toolbox Sorry no thats not what I meant, All i meant is that if the container expands then I dont want the columns to re-order. I just want to the two columns to contain the same amount of the items regardless of its container height. I have actually figured this out so just look at the answer

Comment: @Pete thanks for the help! I have implemented this in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Pete's vague comment (in a good way) I have figured it out.

Example below:

```
<div class="content-box">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
</div>

.content-box {
  columns: 2 auto;
}
```

Literally a CSS one liner haha

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aGByjL